# Detect if my page is a clickjacking destination

Tags: php, iframe, clickjacking

Is there any option to detect if my page is being loaded from a clickjacking page?

I mean, does not matter if the page is the origing of the clickjacking(I've setted the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header), the thing is if from a clickjacked page users are browsing to mine page.

The first solution I found is to control the HTTP-REFERER, but is a hard work because I can't control all my traffic.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you intend for external sites to be able to POST to yours, if you have a POST request originating from another server, it's probably click jacking:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'mydomain.com') {
      //probably clickjacking
}
```

If you have pages that use GET that are susceptible to clickjacking, you can either add a check for the HTTP_REFERER on a per-page basis, or change the page to use POST (which is usually best for something which does an update).

Comment: I've checked some clickjacking pages, I've found that they use a middle page who do the redirection: "header( location: ...)", in that way POST/GET filter is not usefull.

Answer (score 0):

One of your options is to set your website header: "X-Frames-Options" to "SAMEORIGIN"

This should prevent your website from being loaded into iframes and frames unless the originating page is in your domain. 
Note that this will only work for certain browsers, for example I don't think this will work with IE7 and below and I don't think it works with chrome.  This will at least reduce your attack surface a little bit.

Apache:

> Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

[MDN - The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

**EDIT:** Now that I understand better...

Perhaps you can use code similar to this:

```js
if (window.top !== window.self) {
        // do something here
    }
```

This is one way to detect if the page is loaded into an iframe.  You could set a cookie here, call a WebService here, or use window.location.href to navigate.

Here is an example of the "frame-busting" defense for click jacking:
[Clickjacking Defense](https://www.codemagi.com/blog/post/194)

-KB

Comment: Hi Kyle, if I use the X-Frame-Options I avoid to use my page on a iframe. What I'm searching for is a way to detect if my page is accessed by a iframed page.
I mean, doesnt matter if my page is loading in a iframe(anyway the header is set...) what I need is that the ad agencies not use my page as a  clickjacking final destination.

Comment: The x-frame-options header will deny Iframe loads from later versions of IE, Chrome & Firefox. If you're worried about an ad agency fraud, perhaps you can look at the logs to tell if a click jacking was attempted from one of those browsers.  I'm not sure if the server would get a DENY  but there is going to be some sort of signature there. There would at least be a request for the page and then **no** request for your CSS or JavaScript for that page. After that you can stop using that ad agency. Please let us know when you figure out what type of signature to look for.

Comment: I think I'm not explaining it well. Does not matter if my page is loading on a iframe.

Comment: EDIT FROM UPPER:
I think I'm not explaining it well. 
Does not matter if my page is loading on a iframe.
I want to check if I'm the destination of a clickjacked click.